# Exporting specific part of a html page with batch

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, automation

Firstly I'm new to the community as an user, and I want to say it is a great one.

My question is that I want to get an URL from an `<a href=""` element, using `<alt="new">` or the name of an image used in that `<td>` part from a webpage that changes daily and doesn't belong to me.

So far I've coded something to download the page with `wget` to a text file, then searched for the image or alt variable. Even if it brought me the part that the searched items existed, it doesn't include the `<a href` part I needed that's located just before the image.

edit: i managed to get the line below, i just need to get the url inside with batch, or redirect to it with javascript, but since title and url changes, it was challenging. Any help ?

> ```
> <td width="150" align="left" valign="top"><a href="SOMEURL" title="SOMETITLE"><b><u>"SOMETEXT"</u></b></a>
> ```

Comment: Are you talking about Windows batch files or Bash scripts?

Comment: Did you just add the Javascript tag? I don't recall it from yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your provided code:

```
set "x=<td width="150" align="left" valign="top"><a href="SOMEURL" title="SOMETITLE"><b><u>"SOMETEXT"</u></b></a>"

set "x=%x:<=%"              & :: Remove Redirection Character
set "x=%x:>=%"              & :: Remove Redirection Character
set x=%x:*href=%            & :: Remove everything up till href=
set x=%x:~2%                & :: Trim ="
set x=%x:"='%               & :: Replace Double Quotes with Single Quotes
set "x=%x:' =" & rem %      & :: Remove everything after URL

echo %x%
```

Notice the double quotes, they are essential for removing the html tag deliminators `<` and `>`, because those are redirection characters, which will cause errors unless surounded by double quotes.

You can copy and paste the above code directly into the command prompt to test it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you corectly you want do get from HTML file link contained in `<a href=""` ?
first solution that comes to my mind is to download entire HTML and use python and BeautifulSoup library to parse this file and get all 'hrefs'. Is that what you mean?

Comment: mostly yes, but since the page includes many links and only thing i could use to differ the needed ones, is that image, so taking only hrefs wouldnt help. 
BeautifulSoup looks really helpful , but since i dont know python it will take time to use it i guess. Thanks !